# Excel VBA: delete row and append to another worksheet based on date (cell value)

Tags: excel, vba

My script is working, but I still get a bug on the line CDate(S) > Date (Type mismatch error 13).

I would think the date is in the correct format, but apparently not.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

'ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"  'Change password accordingly.

    Dim x As Long
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim MaxRowList As Long
    Dim S As String

    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    iCol = 1
    MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = MaxRowList To 1 Step -1
        S = wsSource.Cells(x, 16)
        If CDate(S) < Date Then
            AfterLastTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsSource.Rows(x).Copy
            wsTarget.Rows(AfterLastTarget).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wsSource.Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'ActiveSheet.Protect "password"  'Change password accordingly.

MsgBox ("Update complete")

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of S when it fails? Also, are you accounting for blank cells?

Comment: The script works, however after having copy/pasted, the error message pops up. I guess I am not accounting for blank cells, but these appear to not be moved then I run the script.

Comment: You can do an If Not IsEmpty(wsSource.Cells(x, 16)) Then ....... but also, what is the value of S when fails?

Comment: Ok, so the script in fact remove blank cells as well. Where do I add that line of code?

Comment: I think the problem is that I have a header in row 1 in the source sheet, which is not a date. How do I modify the MaxRowList to not include the header? Furthermore, the code also delete empty cells. Adding the IsEmpty statement before CDate(S) < Date did not readily work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change `Dim S As Date`

Good luck

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply, however it did not remove the bug. It removes the rows, but ends with run-time error: "13" Type mismatch and the pop up message displaying "Update complete" is not shown. In debug mode the line: If CDate(S) < Date Then is marked yellow. Could it be related to regional date settings?

Comment: Did you try : If IsDate(S) And CDate(S) < Date Then

Comment: Yes, same error code. Date is given as DD-MM-YYYY and cell format is DD-MM-YY.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is the value of S when the bug pop up?

Comment: A2 = 11-11-2017 (the cell row is deleted and appended in sheet2) and
A3 = 11-11-2019 (The cell row remains in sheet1).
The script removes and append as it should, but end with the error message before stating update complete.

Comment: OK, the other solution, please change Dim S As Date

Comment: It works - I was completely blinded by the string to date comparison.

Comment: Great. Just change my answer. Hopefully, you will change the satus as "Answered". Thanks

Comment: Are you available to chat? It seems the solution solved my first problem, but now an old problem occurred, namely that it will not remove 07-11-2018, but only 02-11-2018. In other words, it seems the script only accounts for the number of days and not the month and year.